# Does high CPU usage indicate a software module is designed wrong

Tags: cpu-usage

We have a process that is computationally intensive.  When it runs it typically it uses 99% of the available CPU.   It is configured to take advantage of all available processors so I believe this is OK.  However, one of our customers is complaining because alarms go off on the server on which this process is running because of the high CPU utilization.   I think that there is nothing wrong with high CPU utilization per se.   The CPU drops back to normal when the process stops running and the process does run to completion (no infinite loops, etc.).   I'm just wondering if I am on solid ground when I say that high CPU usage is not a problem per se.

Thank you,

Elliott

Comment: See also [ZOMG... by Raymond Chen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/12/03/10097861.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> if I am on solid ground when I say that high CPU usage is not a problem per se

You are on solid ground.

> We have a process that is computationally intensive

Then I'd expect high CPU usage.

> The CPU drops back to normal when the process stops running

Sounds good so far.

---

Chances are that the systems you client are using are configured to notify when the CPU usage goes over a certain limit, as sometimes this is indicative of a problem (and sustained high usage can cause over heating and associated problems).

If this is expected behavior, your client needs to adjust their monitoring - but you need to ensure that the behavior is as expected on their systems and that it is not likely to cause problems (ensure that high CPU usage is not sustained).

Answer (score 1):

Alarm is not a viable reason for poor design. The real reason may be that it chokes other tasks on the system.  Modern OSes usually take care of this by lowering dynamic priority of the CPU hungry process in such a way that others that are less demanding of CPU time will get higher priority.  You may tell the customer to "nice" the process to start with, since you probably don't care if it runs 10 mins of 12 mins. Just my 2 cents :)